# How do I get contents of a Google Wave given the wave id and wavelet id?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-wave

I am using the robots api. I have a wave id and wavelet id, and my app's email is added to the wave. How can I simply get the wave (or wavelet's) contents using the python api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the example [here](http://code.google.com/apis/wave/extensions/robots/python-tutorial.html):

```
def OnWaveletSelfAdded(event, wavelet):
  for id in wavelet.blips:
    blip = wavelet.blips[id]
    logging.debug(blip.text)
```

Comment: Thanks, How about by using the Active Robots API?

Comment: wavelet = robot.fetch_wavelet(wave_id, wavelet_id)

Comment: That comment was the anwer. Thank you. But I am getting a 502 http error IOError: HttpError 502